# How can i get live feed from a live camera?

Tags: c#, winforms

For example there is this camera online:

```
http://cam-i.switch.ch/login.cgi?t=j&l=1&ch=2
```

Its using java.
I want to get the image from the camera every X seconds and show it on a pictureBox.

This is the code im trying to use:

```
string sourceURL = "http://cam-i.switch.ch/login.cgi?t=j&l=1&ch=2";
            byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
            int read, total = 0;
            // create HTTP request
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sourceURL);
            req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pass");
            // get response
            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            // get response stream
            Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
            // read data from stream
            while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, total, 1000)) != 0)
            {
                total += read;
            }
            // get bitmap
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(
                          new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, total));

            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Im getting ArgumentException on this line:

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(
                          new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, total));
```

I see that buffer contain many numbers and total contain 15149
Parameter is not valid

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
       at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)
       at SearchLiveCameras.Form1..ctor() in d:\C-Sharp\SearchliveCameras\SearchLiveCameras\SearchLiveCameras\Form1.cs:line 43
       at SearchLiveCameras.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\SearchliveCameras\SearchLiveCameras\SearchLiveCameras\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I want to make that every online camera link i put in i will get the live feed on pictureBox1

Comment: That link gives you an HTML page containing a java applet. You are trying to load the html into a bitmap, which can't work. You need a link that gives you a raw image.

Comment: There's no 1 way to do this. The answer will vary depending on the codecs and such utilized by the camera and viewing app. Beyond that, you'll need to be able to access the live feed directly rather than the HTML page used for display.